# Why do Python modules behave differently in virtualenv than in system environment?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, python-requests, virtualenv

I've finally realized the advantages of virtual environments for my projects, having all modules/versions contained within the project could save me from the regular headache whenever I'm trying to use old scripts/projects.

However, it seems it's not that easy. For some reason the requests-module behaves different in my virtual environment than when using the system environment (specifically the **`requests`** module).

**Here's how I've initialized the virtual environment for my project (cmd):**

```
:: SETTING UP A VIRTUAL ENVIRONMENT (PYTHON 2.7) AND INSTALLING MODULES
D:\Projects\MyProject>"C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe" install virtualenv
D:\Projects\MyProject>"C:\Python27\Scripts\virtualenv.exe" venv
D:\Projects\MyProject>venv\Scripts\activate.bat
D:\Projects\MyProject>pip install -r requirements.txt
```

### **What I don't Understand:**

**`where python`** and **`where pip`** points correctly to the virtual environment. **`python -V`** and **`pip -V`** returns the same version as in my system environment (python 2.7 & pip 20.3.4). When comparing the modules through **`pip freeze`** I have the correct modules and versions.

But even though I have identical python/pip-version and modules/module-versions in my virtual environment (as I have in my system environment), the virtual environment throws this error (below), but in my system environment everything works fine.

**Why does this happen (and how can I fix it)?**



**The error message I get (when executed from the virtual environment):**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myScript_performWebQuery.py", line 504, in <module>
    searchResult = fn_RetrieveTitle(varInput[0], varInput[1])
  File "myScript_performWebQuery.py", line 162, in fn_RetrieveTitle
    searchResult_Request = requests.get(urlQueryStr), headers={"User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Trident/7.0; like Gecko"})
  File "...\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "...\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "...\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "...\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "...\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /test-sites/e-commerce/allinone (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)'),))
```

**My virtual environment modules (`pip freeze`):**

```
backports.functools-lru-cache==1.6.4
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi==1.15.1
chardet==4.0.0
cryptography==3.3.2
docopt==0.6.2
enum34==1.1.10
ez-setup==0.9
idna==2.10
ipaddress==1.0.23
lxml==4.6.3
ndg-httpsclient==0.5.1
num2words==0.5.12
numpy==1.16.6
opencv-python==4.2.0.32
pyasn1==0.4.8
pycparser==2.21
pyOpenSSL==21.0.0
pysrt==1.1.2
requests==2.25.1
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==1.9.6
urllib3==1.26.12
```

I'm on Windows 10 (if that has any relevance).

Comment: It looks like `requests` installed in your virtual environment doesn't know where to find a list of trusted certificate authorities. It's possible simply installing [`pip-system-certs`](https://pypi.org/project/pip-system-certs/) will fix that problem, but I don't have a Windows host on which to try.

Comment: @larsks Thank's for your suggestion. Unfortunately installing pip-system-cert didn't help. Do you know how I can find out if your hypothesis for the cause is correct?